# generic repository - update method

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have objects: orderToEdit (with values from user) and originalOrder (with values from database) - they have the same primary key of course. I would like to update existing record using new values from user. But I can't because originalOrder is tracking by Entity Framework so I have error:

```
>     An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
> 
>     Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'Blog.Model.Entities.Orders' failed because another entity of the same
> type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when
> using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
> 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
> conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
> have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
> the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
> then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
> appropriate.
```

Method in service - here I don't have access to database context:

```
public void EditOrder(Orders orderToEdit) // orderToEdit object has values from user
{
    Orders originalOrder = _ordersService.GetOrder(orderToEdit.OrderId);

    if (originalOrder == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(404);
    }

    orderToEdit.CreateDate = originalOrder.CreateDate; 

    _unitOfWork.OrdersRepository.Update(orderToEdit); // Update method it is the method which you can see below
    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

This is method to update entity in generic repository class from Microsoft tutorial - here I have access to database context:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
public virtual void Update(T entityToUpdate)
{
    dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
    context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

How should I modify Update method in generic repository?

Answer (score 1):

Fill the Original order that you got from database with the modified one and save that like

```
public void EditOrder(Orders orderToEdit) // orderToEdit object has values from user
    {
        Orders originalOrder = _ordersService.GetOrder(orderToEdit.OrderId);
        if (originalOrder == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404);
        }

        //Fill the originalOrder with the modified One like
        originalOrder.CreateDate = orderToEdit.CreateDate;  // Do same with other properties

        //Now save the original order
        _unitOfWork.OrdersRepository.Update(originalOrder);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Or maybe better way is to add to generic repository that method:

public virtual void Update(T originalEntity, T entityToUpdate)
{             context.Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entityToUpdate);
}
??

Comment: depends like there might be lot of scenarios where you want to modify only few properties of an entity and also passing only those entities while calling the PUT method. That's why i like PATCH in ODataController  :)